# My MacBook Pro is taking time to load after signin

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

I'm facing strange issue with my new MacBookPro(4GB RAM). It is taking more time to load apps after signin. And when I click on any app, it is stopped responding for some time.

I did FirstAid to my both drives(one is Macintosh, 2nd is other data drive) to find and repair what is going wrong, but result was success(Nothing to repair).

**UPDATE:**  per the suggestion in the comments, I created a new user account and now my MBP works correctly when signed into the **new** account.  What could be in my *old* account that's causing the problem?

I issued the command below to get the size of my home folder:

```
sudo du -d1 -h /Users
```

Results:

```
190M    /Users/bujji
4.6G    /Users/Nagendra
364K    /Users/Shared
4.8G    /Users
```

Comment: If you create another account and log into it, does the problem persist?

Comment: @Allan I haven't tried that way. But how it relates to that?

Comment: You may have a corruped profile, you might be loading something in yours - it can be any number of things.  If it's present in a new profile then it's system wide and we have an idea how to proceed.

Comment: @Allan I've created new profile and seems it is working fine. Now how to find old account issue?

Comment: First thing is to see what's different between the two.  The most obvious place I would look is under "Users" in "System Preferences."  Go to "startup items" and see what is being loaded.  Also keep in mind, the profile just may have been corrupted (bad data) which is something you may not be able to find.

Comment: You have 4.6GB of stuff in your *old* profile.  You can use Finder or Terminal, to start exploring your old profile directory.  Specifically, I am interested in what isn `/Users/your-username/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: @Allan Nothing is there in this location.

Comment: @Allan Not sure, what was the issue. Now Mac is working fast like earlier.

Comment: It is most likely a corrupted file.  The OS was trying to load something and it was causing it problems.  The new account solved it.

Comment: @Allan No, Actually I have created new account and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there's some corruption in your old account.

What you need to do is two fold:

1. Make the new account your primary with the intention of eventually deleting your old account.
2. Incrementally copy of files and settings from the old profile to the new one until all the files are transferred.

You want to do this in small batches because you don't know what is corrupted and what isn't.  Now, it's highly likely you won't have a problem with documents, pictures, movies and music.  However, there may be a setting (file) for an application that is causing the issue.

If after a copy, things go awry, you will have narrowed down where the offending file is.

All in all, **the solution was and is to create a new user account.**